# A complex picture with lots of curved arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I have a figure that I need to add to my working. But I don't understand how to make or start. Can anyone please help?[image]

Comment: You have already the tags `tikz-pgf` and `chemfig`. Start with these packages and make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick draft.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
            draw = none,
            rectangle,
            inner sep = 0.2em,
            node distance = 2em
        ]
    \node (caco3) {CaCO$_3$};
    \node[below = of caco3] (plusco2) {+CO$_2$};
    \node[left = of plusco2] (cao) {CaO};
    \node[below left = of cao] (h2o) {H$_2$O};
    \node[below = of plusco2] (nahco3) {NaHCO$_3$};
    \node[below = of nahco3] (cplush2o) {C+H$_2$O};
    \node[below left = of cplush2o] (a) {A};
    \node[below right = of plusco2] (b) {B};
    \node[above right = of b] (nh3h2o) {NH$_3 \cdot$H$_2$O};
    \node[below = of b] (plusd) {+D};
    \node[below right = of b] (nacl) {NaCl};
    \node[below = of nacl] (nh3h2oe) {NH$_3$+H$_2$O+E};

    % Scope to add arrow tips.
    \begin{scope}[-latex]
        \draw (caco3) to (plusco2);
        \draw[bend right] (cao) to node[midway] (midcaoa) {} (a);
        \draw[bend left] (h2o) to (midcaoa);
        \draw[bend right] (plusco2.south west) to node[pos = 0.3] (midplusco2cplush2o) {} (cplush2o.north west);
        \draw[bend right] (nahco3) to (midplusco2cplush2o);
        \draw[bend left] (plusco2) to node[midway] (midplusco2b) {} (b);
        \draw[bend left] (midplusco2b) to (nh3h2o.west);
        \draw (b) to node[midway] (midbplusd) {} (plusd);
        \draw[bend right] (nacl) to (midbplusd);
        \draw[bend left] (nh3h2o) to (nh3h2oe);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'll let you adjust the positions etc. And give a try to the `chemmacros` package, as suggested by dexteritas in a comment, to print the names of the chemical entities.

[image]

Comment: You can use `\ch{H_2O}` etc. from `chemmacros`.